# Sum of neighbours

Tags: code-golf

This should be a fairly simple challenge.

For an array of numbers, generate an array where for every element all neighbouring elements are added to itself, and return the sum of that array.

Here is the transformation which occurs on the input array `[1,2,3,4,5]`

```
[1,2,3,4,5] => [1+2, 2+1+3, 3+2+4, 4+3+5, 5+4] => [3,6,9,12,9] => 39
 0          => neighbours of item 0, including item 0
[1,2]       => 1 + 2      => 3
   1
[1,2,3]     => 1 + 2 + 3  => 6
     2
  [2,3,4]   => 2 + 3 + 4  => 9
       3
    [3,4,5] => 3 + 4 + 5  => 12
         4
      [4,5] => 4 + 5      => 9

               3+6+9+12+9 => 39
```

#### Test cases

```
[]            => 0 (or falsy)
[1]           => 1
[1,4]         => 10 (1+4 + 4+1)
[1,4,7]       => 28
[1,4,7,10]    => 55
[-1,-2,-3]    => -14
[0.1,0.2,0.3] => 1.4
[1,-20,300,-4000,50000,-600000,7000000] => 12338842
```

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=96188,OVERRIDE_USER=41257;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75432/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61321/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69102/8478)

Comment: Do we need to support floating point numbers or only integers?

Comment: @corvus_192 The test cases include non-integers.

Comment: @Geobits I didn't notice that, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You should do this with 2 dimensional arrays next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
7BZ+s
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=N0JaK3M&input=WzEsLTIwLDMwMCwtNDAwMCw1MDAwMCwtNjAwMDAwLDcwMDAwMDBd)

#### Explanation

```
7B  % Push array [1, 1, 1], obtained as 7 in binary
Z+  % Take input implicitly. Convolve with [1, 1, 1], keeping size
s   % Sum of resulting array. Display implicitly
```

Comment: Very clever use of `7B` there to get `[1 1 1]`

Comment: I don't know MATL, but I wonder: for a list `[a,b,c,...]`, how do you get `a+b` but avoid getting `a`?

Comment: @Christian The addition is done by means of a convolution operation. It would produce the partial results you refer to, but there's a version of convolution that avoids them, because it produces an output array with only as many entries as the input. This is also used in Suever's answer

Answer (score 20):

## Python, 25 bytes

```
lambda a:sum((a*3)[1:-1])
```

To see why this works, rotate the expansion in the OP by 45 degrees:

```
             1 + 2                        
           + 1 + 2 + 3                            2 + 3 + 4 + 5
               + 2 + 3 + 4          =       + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
                   + 3 + 4 + 5              + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4.
                       + 4 + 5
```

Answer (score 14):

## Python 2, 28 bytes

```
lambda a:sum(a)*3-a[0]-a[-1]
```

Just 3 times the sum and minus one of each end element

Comment: I also found a neat [25-byte solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96217/3852).

Comment: Actually, what if `a` is the empty list (first test case)? `a[0]` will throw an `IndexError`, no?

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 5 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to *Adnan*.

```
€Ð¦¨O
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oKsw5DCpsKoTw&input=WzEsLTIwLDMwMCwtNDAwMCw1MDAwMCwtNjAwMDAwLDcwMDAwMDBd)

**Explanation**

```
€Ð     # triplicate each item in the list
  ¦¨   # remove first and last element
    O  # sum
```

Comment: Does `€Ð¦¨O` work :)?

Comment: @Adnan: Brilliant! I tried to think of a way to do it with 3*, but I never even considered `€Ð` even though I've used `€D` before :P

Answer (score 4):

### R, <strike>75 70 52 34 33</strike> 31 bytes

Sum times three and subtract first and last element

```
sum(x<-scan())*3-x[1]-tail(x,1)
```

Edit: Saved 3 extra bytes thanks to @rturnbull

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>40</s> 33 bytes

```
l=>eval(l.join`+`)*3-l[0]-l.pop()
```

Returns `NaN` when given an empty list.

Comment: You can chop off 2 more characters if you move the multiplication into the join like so `v=>eval(v.join\`*3+\`+"*2")-v[0]`

Comment: @Grax - Nice! However, it would not be falsy anymore for the empty array.

Comment: There's always something isn't there?

Comment: @Grax - No. The first test case is an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 47 bytes

```
def&(a:Float*)=(0+:a:+0)sliding 3 map(_.sum)sum
```

Prepends and appends a 0, then uses a sliding window of size 3 to sum the neighbors, and calculates the total sum

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, 72 Bytes

```
float c(float[]a){float s=0,l=0;for(float i:a)s+=l=i;return 3*s-l-a[0];}
```

Comment: I don't think adding extra inputs denoting the first and last elements of the array is in the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: @Geobits I change it.....

Comment: Cool. You can golf it some more by using `float` instead of `double` :)

Comment: Can i use it instead.... Double has 2x the precision of float.

Comment: I usually do, and it's never come up as an issue.

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but this fails for an empty input (`c(new float[] { })`)

Comment: Also for the last test input, your function returns `1.2338843E7` which is equal to `12338843`

Comment: why not `int`s?

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes

*Taking some inspiration Lynn's neat [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96217/8478)...*

```
Check[3Tr@#-Last@#-#[[1]],0]&
```

or

```
Check[3(+##)-#&@@#-Last@#,0]&
```

or

```
Check[##-#/3&@@#*3-Last@#,0]&
```

Unfortunately, this approach isn't quite as convenient in Mathematica as it is in Python, because there's no short and safe way to discard the first and last element of a list that might be empty.

Comment: +1 for teaching me `Check`

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @Luis*

```
@(x)sum(conv(x,1:3>0,'s'))
```

This creates an anonymous function named `ans` that can be called like: `ans([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

In order to provide an online demo (which uses Octave), I had to use `'same'` instead of `'s'` as the last input to `conv`

[**Online Demo**](http://ideone.com/RB0j0J)

**Explanation**

We perform convolution (`conv`) with a `1 x 3` kernel of all 1's (created by making an array `1:3` and then comparing to zero `>0`) and keep the size of the original by specifying the third input as `'same'` or in MATLAB we can simply shorten this to `'s'`. We then apply the sum to the result.

Comment: You can probably shorten to `'s'`

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh good call! MATLAB allows it but Octave doesn't (of course)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ẋ3ṖḊS
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bqLM-G5luG4ilM&input=)

Translation of my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96217/3852).

```
ẋ3      Concatenate three copies of the input list
  Ṗ     Remove the last element
   Ḋ    Remove the first element
    S   Sum
```

Comment: So many 5 byters, where's the 4? `ḊṖ+ḤS`, `Ṗ++ḊS`, `+Ḋ+ṖS`, `+Ṗ+ḊS`, ...

Answer (score 2):

## J, 9 bytes

```
+/@,}.,}:
```

For `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, the neighbors are

```
1 2 3 4 5
1+2
1+2+3
  2+3+4
    3+4+5
      4+5
```

Then look along the diagonals of the sums

```
(2+3+4+5)+(1+2+3+4+5)+(1+2+3+4)
```

So we need only the find the sum of the input with its head removed and with its tail removed.

### Usage

```
   f =: +/@,}.,}:
   f 1 2 3 4 5
39
   f '' NB. Empty array
0
   f 1
1
   f 1 4
10
   f 1 4 7
28
   f 1 4 7 10
55
   f _1 _2 _3
_14
   f 0.1 0.2 0.3
1.4
   f 1 _20 300 _4000 50000 _600000 7000000
12338842
```

### Explanation

```
+/@,}.,}:  Input: array A
       }:  Return a list with the last value in A removed
    }.     Return a list with the first value in A removed
      ,    Join them
   ,       Join that with A
+/@        Reduce that using addition to find the sum and return
```

Comment: Nice. And happy 6k+!

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

Inspired by Lynn's solution:

```
->a{[*(a*3)[1..-2]].reduce:+}
```

The `to_a` segment is there to handle the empty array.

EDIT: Thanks to m-chrzan and histocrat.

Comment: You don't need parentheses around `:+`.

Comment: `[*(a*3)[1..-2]]` does `.to_a` in two fewer bytes.

Comment: You might want to give Ruby 2.4.0 a go. It comes with `Array#sum`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 68 bytes

```
(<><>)([]){{}({}({})<>{})<>({}<(({})<>{})><>)([][()()])}{}({}{}<>{})
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KDw-PD4pKFtdKXt7fSh7fSh7fSk8Pnt9KTw-KHt9PCgoe30pPD57fSk-PD4pKFtdWygpKCldKX17fSh7fXt9PD57fSk&input=MQoyCjMKNAo1)

Explanation:

```
#Push a 0
(<><>)

#Push the stack height
([])

#While true:
{

    #Pop the stack height 
    {}

    #Add the sum of the top 3 elements to the other stack, and pop the top of the stack
    ({}({})<>{})<>({}<(({})<>{})><>)

    #Push the new stack height minus two
    ([][()()])

#End
}

#Pop the exhausted counter
{}

#Add the top two numbers to the other stack
({}{}<>)
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 40 bytes

```
param($a)($a-join'+'|iex)*3-$a[0]-$a[-1]
```

Similar to the other answers, sums the list, multiplies by 3, subtracts the end elements. Barfs out a spectacular error for empty input, and then spits out `0`, but since STDERR is ignored by default, this is OK.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sum-of-neighbors.ps1 @()
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\sum-of-neighbors.ps1:1 char:22
+ param($a)($a-join'+'|iex)*3-$a[0]-$a[-1]
+                      ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:String) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

0

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sum-of-neighbors.ps1 @(1)
1

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sum-of-neighbors.ps1 @(1,4)
10

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sum-of-neighbors.ps1 @(1,4,7)
28

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sum-of-neighbors.ps1 @(1,4,7,10)
55

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sum-of-neighbors.ps1 @(-1,-2,-3)
-14

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sum-of-neighbors.ps1 @(0.1,0.2,0.3)
1.4

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\sum-of-neighbors.ps1 @(1,-20,300,-4000,50000,-600000,7000000)
12338842
```

Comment: `ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed` ಠ_ಠ What an exception!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```perl6
{.sum*3-.[0]-(.[*-1]//0)}    # generates warning
{+$_&&.sum*3-.[0]-.[*-1]}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
# bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
{
  +$_        # the number of elements

  &&         # if that is 0 return 0, otherwise return the following

  .sum * 3   # sum them up and multiply by 3
  - .[ 0 ]   # subtract the first value
  - .[*-1]   # subtract the last value
}
```

### Test:

```perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

my &code = {+$_&&.sum*3-.[0]-.[*-1]}

my @tests = (
  []            => 0,
  [1]           => 1,
  [1,4]         => 10,
  [1,4,7]       => 28,
  [1,4,7,10]    => 55,
  [-1,-2,-3]    => -14,
  [0.1,0.2,0.3] => 1.4,
  [1,-20,300,-4000,50000,-600000,7000000] => 12338842,
);

plan +@tests;

for @tests -> $_ ( :key(@input), :value($expected) ) {
  is code(@input), $expected, .gist;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# with LINQ, 42 bytes

```
a=>3*a.Sum()-(a.Length>0?a[0]+a.Last():0);
```

Requires the `System.Linq` namespace.

---

## C#, 84 bytes

```
a=>{int i=0,l=a.Length;var r=0d;for(;i<l;)r+=3*a[i++];return(l>0?r-a[0]-a[l-1]:0);};
```

Full program with test cases:

```
using System;

namespace SumOfNeighbours
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<double[],double>f= a=>{int i=0,l=a.Length;var r=0d;for(;i<l;)r+=3*a[i++];return(l>0?r-a[0]-a[l-1]:0);};
            
            
            // test cases:
            double[] x = new double[]{1,2,3,4,5};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // 39
            
            x = new double[] {};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // 0
            
            x = new double[] {1};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // 1
            
            x = new double[] {1,4};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // 10 (1+4 + 4+1)
            
            x = new double[] {1,4,7};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // 28
            
            x = new double[] {1,4,7,10};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // 55
            
            x = new double[] {-1,-2,-3};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // -14
            
            x = new double[] {0.1,0.2,0.3};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // 1.4
            
            x = new double[] {1,-20,300,-4000,50000,-600000,7000000};
            Console.WriteLine(f(x));    // 12338842
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 39 bytes

```
<?=3*array_sum($a=$argv)-$a[1]-end($a);
```

Run like this:

```
echo '<?=3*array_sum($a=$argv)-$a[1]-end($a);' | php -- 1 -20 300 -4000 50000 -600000 7000000 2>/dev/null;echo
```

## Explanation

Challenge can be reduced to adding every number 3 times, except the first and last number (added twice). Therefore I return 3 times the sum, minus the first and last number.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 67 bytes

```
@set/as=l=0
@for %%n in (%*)do @set/as+=l=%%n
@cmd/cset/as*3-%1-l
```

If there are no parameters, the last command turns into `0 * 3 - -0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 25 (+3 for  `-v`) = 28 bytes

Takes input from the stack with  `-v` and assumes stdin is empty, relying on it to provide a `-1` value.

```
:{:}+i*v
:$v?=1l<+++:
;n<
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 48 bytes

```
(if(null? l)0(-(* 3(apply + l))(car l)(last l)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (- (* 3 (apply + lst))
         (first lst)
         (last lst))))
```

Testing:

```
(f '()) 
(f '(1))
(f '(1 4)) 
(f '(1 4 7)) 
(f '(1 4 7 10)) 
(f '(-1 -2 -3)) 
(f '(0.1 0.2 0.3)) 
(f '(1 -20 300 -4000 50000 -600000 7000000))
```

Output:

```
0
1
10
28
55
-14
1.4000000000000001
12338842
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gloo](https://github.com/kade-robertson/gloo), 12 Bytes

Turns out a feature of Gloo isn't working as intended so I had to do this a painful way.

```
__]:]:]:,,[+
```

Explanation:

```
__                   // duplicate the input list twice
  ]:]:]:             // flatten each list, and rotate stack left 
        ,,           // pop the last 2 numbers 
                     // (which are the first and last element of the list)
          [+         // wrap all items in a list and sum.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, <s>9</s> 5 bytes

```
3*tOs
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=3%2atOs&input=%5B1%2C4%2C7%2C10%5D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/), 93 bytes

```
&if (length(&1)>0),do: Enum.reduce(&1,fn(n,r)->n+r end)*3-Enum.at(&1,0)-List.last(&1),else: 0
```

Anonymous function using the capture operator.

Full program with test cases:

```
s=&if (length(&1)>0),do: Enum.reduce(&1,fn(n,r)->n+r end)*3-Enum.at(&1,0)-List.last(&1),else: 0
# test cases:
IO.puts s.([])            # 0
IO.puts s.([1])           # 1
IO.puts s.([1,4])         # 10 (1+4 + 4+1)
IO.puts s.([1,4,7])       # 28
IO.puts s.([1,4,7,10])    # 55
IO.puts s.([-1,-2,-3])    # -14
IO.puts s.([0.1,0.2,0.3]) # 1.4
IO.puts s.([1,-20,300,-4000,50000,-600000,7000000]) # 12338842
```

**Try it online on [ElixirPlayground](http://elixirplayground.com/) !**

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 17 bytes

Simply three times the sum of the list, minus the first and last element.

```
3sum(Ans)-Ans(1)-Ans(dim(Ans)-1
```

Comment: I believe consensus on meta says that `Ans` is an invalid form of input.

Comment: You can use it with a list, don't worry. Pass it like `{1,3,5,7,2,6}:prgmNEIGHBOR`

Comment: That's still `Ans` as input.

Comment: Does it look like I care? That's the standard way of passing input in TI-Basic.

Comment: as much as I agree with you, that doesn't make the answer any more valid.

Comment: It is most definitely valid. Try it yourself. Anyone else doesn't know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

## GameMaker Language, 69 bytes

```
a=argument_count;for(i=0;i<a;)s+=argument[i++]*(3-(i=1||i=a))return s
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 41 bytes

```
->a{a.reduce(0,:+)*3-(a[0]?a[0]+a[-1]:0)}
```

Full program with test cases:

```
f=->a{a.reduce(0,:+)*3-(a[0]?a[0]+a[-1]:0)}

#test cases
a=[]            
puts f.call(a)  # 0

a=[1]           
puts f.call(a)  # 1

a=[1,4]         
puts f.call(a)  # 10

a=[1,4,7]       
puts f.call(a)  # 28

a=[1,4,7,10]    
puts f.call(a)  # 55

a=[-1,-2,-3]    
puts f.call(a)  # -14

a=[0.1,0.2,0.3] 
puts f.call(a)  # 1.4

a=[1,-20,300,-4000,50000,-600000,7000000] 
puts f.call(a)  # 12338842
```

My first attempt in Ruby.

Comment: As of Ruby 2.4.0 there's `Array#sum`. I haven't yet installed the preview release though to test whether this can simply be dropped into this solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 46 bytes

```
a.reduce((t,c,i)=>t+(a[i-1]|0)+c+(a[i+1]|0),0)
```

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(a.reduce((t,c,i)=>t+(a[i-1]|0)+c+(a[i+1]|0),0));
```

Thanks @rlemon for the extra 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 60

```
d->d.length>0?Arrays.stream(d).sum()*3-d[0]-d[d.length-1]:0;
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 67 bytes

```
#import<valarray>
int f(std::valarray<int>v){return 3*v.sum()-v[0]-v[v.size()-1];}
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << f({1,2,1});
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 25 bytes

From fastest

```
sum.sequence[(0-).head,(3*).sum,(0-).last]$[1..5]
```

via prettiest

```
sum.sequence[sum.init,sum,sum.tail]$[1..5]
```

down to ugliest but shortest

```
let y x=sum$init x++x++tail x in y[1..5]     
--  1234567890123456789012345
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 9 bytes

Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=M0BWZFhwWM6jzqM&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNV0)

```
3@VdXpXΣΣ
```

**Ungolfing**

```
       Implicit input a.
3@V    Push all slices of a of length 1 <= n <= 3.
dXpX   Get rid of the first and last slices since they're length 1 lists.
Σ      Summing a 2D array essentially flattens into a 1D array.
Σ      Push sum(a).
       Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 21 bytes

`yGPP<C-V>GI+<Esc>DgvJD^C<C-R>=<C-R>"<CR>`

Input is one number per line. Same algorithm as other entries (triplicate array, remove first and last items, sum).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>10</s> <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
sPt*3
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to implicit input, and 1 byte thanks to the `P` function (replaces `t_` in the previous solution)

---

**Previous versions:**

```
st_t*3Q
```

Concatenates the array 3 times, removes first and last elements, and sums it up

```
-*3sQ+eQhQ
```

The final sum is 3 times the sum of the elements - first element - last element.
That's exactly what this code does :)

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-%2A3sQ%2BeQhQ&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D&debug=1)**

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, <s>64</s> 59 bytes

As unnamed lambda

```c++
[](auto c,int&r){r=-c[0];for(auto x:c)r+=3*x;r-=c.back();}
```

Initializes counter with `-c[0]`, then sums all elements times `3` and subtracts the last element. This gives `3*sum(c)-c.first-c.last` which is the direct formula for this problem.

Takes any container that supports `.back()`. If you insinst on using plain old arrays (*örglöärks*) then substitute `c.back()` with `std::end(c)[-1]` for **+7 bytes**.

Usage:

```c++
auto n=[](auto c,int&r){r=-c[0];for(auto x:c)r+=3*x;r-=c.back();};

std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
//or// std::array<int,5> v{1,2,3,4,5};
//or// int v[]={1,2,3,4,5}; //with std::end(c)[-1]
int r;
n(v,r);
std::cout << r << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429)

```apl
+/¯1↓1↓3/⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1v/0HrDR22TQdhY/1HXov9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/h/msKj3jUKCPCod66CAVeagiGamCFYzARVzAAqaI4kaGQBFzQ0gAmamgIFga4DYiMgNoaJ6xqaACUM9AyB2AiIjSHm6pmAzQAqNlAwNjAAMkwMgJSpgQGYY2YAZpgbQGiwFiNjYwsLEyMA)

### Explanation

Use the same observation as [a previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96217/26977) that the result is the sum of 3x the elements minus the first and last.

```apl
+/¯1↓1↓3/⊢ ⍝ Function train. Below explanation uses a sample input of 1 2 3
       3/⊢ ⍝ Repeats (/) each element of the right hand side (⊢) three times - 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
     1↓    ⍝ Drops (↓) the first item of the array -> 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
  ¯1↓      ⍝ Drops (↓) the last item (¯1) of the array -> 1 1 2 2 2 3 3
+/         ⍝ Sum over the array -> 14
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
€Ðḣṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMiU4MiVBQyVDMyU5MCVFMSVCOCVBMyVFMSVCOSVBQiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSU1QjElMkMtMjAlMkMzMDAlMkMtNDAwMCUyQzUwMDAwJTJDLTYwMDAwMCUyQzcwMDAwMDAlNUQmZmxhZ3M9U2U=)

Port of Emigna's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
€Ðḣṫ  # Implicit input
€     # To each item in the input:
 Ð    #  Triplicate in-place
  ḣ   # Remove the first item
   ṫ  # Remove the last item
      # Sum the resulting list
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>49</s> 45 bytes

(27 if you don't count the using statement)

```
using System.Linq;v=>v.Sum()*3-v[0]-v.Last();
```

Comment: `Sum()*3` saves 4 bytes